# Is "recommend me XXX" subjective questions?

Tags: discussion, subjective

Am I being over overzealous for trying to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975159/orm-for-simple-net-app) as subjective?

I'm wondering since it got a lot of answers, even from persons with higher rank.

Comment: I wouldn't call it subjective, but it doesn't have a definite answer. `Too localized` comes to mind.

Comment: Then how is a correct answer chosen for that question?

Comment: does it really have to be a *correct* answer? isn't an *accepted* answer enough?

Comment: @Jonas: Last time I checked, [no, it's not enough](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). Just because something has an *accepted* answer doesn't turn it into a good or on-topic question. The question is close to hitting the second point in the FAQ.

Comment: @Bobby: in some cases it is. See the link about "six guidelines for great subjective questions" in the FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't call it subjective, since the "asker" does not ask "What is the best ORM"etc. He just asks for recommendations on where to look, and the answerers are giving him some insight. I wouldn't call it subjective probably.

Comment: It's still subjective. But some subjective questions are allowed.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose so, it's probably subjective to the point that no answer could be considered as "the correct one".

Comment: The closing reason includes also "argumentative." If that question is not subjective, then it is at least argumentative.